# I can't get multiple same ids to execute the same script

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, getelementbyid

I want to create scroll-to-top buttons.

This is my code in JS. The problem is that even though I have 3 buttons with the same id I can only use only one everytime I load the page.  Why is this happening? What should I do?

**UPDATE**

I didn't know that I could only use ID once. I tried all the suggested solutions but for some reason the **getElementsByClassName** doesn't work either. :(

**The solution was to replace with:**

```
$('.scrolltotop').on('click', function(){/* do your stuff */});
```

Here is my html too:

```
<ul class="stats">
<li class="scrolltotop"><a href="#">GO TO TOP</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('scrolltotop').onclick = function () {
 scrollTo(document.body, 0, 100);
}

    function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
        if (duration < 0) return;
        var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
        var perTick = difference / duration * 2;

    setTimeout(function() {
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
        scrollTo(element, to, duration - 2);
    }, 10);
}
```

Comment: You can only have one element with same id on the page. Use class instead.

Comment: I didn't know that !! Thanks for the input..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New code. This should work.

`getElementsByClassName` will only return you `array-like object` of all the elements having the class name. You have to loop it and assign it one by one.

```
var classData = (document.getElementsByClassName('scrolltotop'));
for(var i = 0; i < classData.length; i++)
{
    classData[i].onclick = function()
    {
        scrollTo(document.body, 0, 100);
    }
}
function scrollTo(element, to, duration)
{
    if(duration < 0) return;
    var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
    var perTick = difference / duration * 2;

    setTimeout(function()
    {
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
        scrollTo(element, to, duration - 2);
    }, 10);
}
```

Another way to do it easily is to use jQuery.

```
$('.scrolltotop').on('click', function(){/* do your stuff */});
```

Comment: At the end it was simpler  than we though :) The second way you suggested worked pretty well :) thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of id if you have to use it multiple times. Id is only meant to be used once, while class can be used any number of times. getElementById() should still work with classes.

Comment: "_getElementById() should still work with classes_" No, otherwise it would be `getElementWithIdOrElementsWithClass` ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Do not create markup that contains elements with duplicate IDs.** This will break things, and you will be [mauled by a velociraptor faster than you can say `"goto"`](http://xkcd.com/292/).

Use **classes** instead:

```
<img src='...' class='scrolltotop' />
<img src='...' class='scrolltotop' />
document.getElementsWithClass('scrolltotop').onclick = function () {
   scrollTo(document.body, 0, 100);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like list of elements. You have to iterate over the elements in it to assign an event handler.

Answer (score -1):

Please use class for it as id is unique for each element

```
 var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("scrolltotop");


for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].onclick = function () {
     scrollTo(document.body, 0, 100);
    }
 }

function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
    if (duration < 0) return;
    var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
    var perTick = difference / duration * 2;

   setTimeout(function() {
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
    scrollTo(element, to, duration - 2);
   }, 10);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like list of elements. You have to iterate over the elements in it to assign an event handler.